# Problem retrieving utf-8 string from mysql using hibernate3

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, utf-8

When I try to load an object( a row ) from mysql database, the string properties are not loaded properly , and as a result when I print them, nothing is displayed.

here is my hibernate config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>    
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
       com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_hib_1
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"> </property>
    <property name="pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <!-- Mapping files -->

     <mapping resource="com/navid/Person.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tryed adding encoding to connection url :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_hib_1&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

and got hibernate exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at com.navid.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 10 of document  : The reference to entity "characterEncoding" must end with the ';' delimiter. Nested exception: The reference to entity "characterEncoding" must end with the ';' delimiter.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: How do you "print" string properties?  Have you checked in a debugger that the data coming back from MySQL is indeed rubbish or whether it is the printing that doesn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hibernate config file is an XML file, so raw & symbols aren't allowed

Two options that spring to mind (but untested!), the first would be to use the XML `&amp;` escape sequence:

```
<property name="connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_hib_1?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
</property>
```

Or using name+value syntax, which wouldn't need the & escaping:

```
<property name="connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_hib_1?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
```

Note that I've added a 2nd option too, I think you need both

Comment: I used &amp escaping and exception does not occure. but I still have the original problem : strings are not printed properly. when I print any string attribute I get a blank string whose length is twice as long as the original string stored in the database.

Comment: The "twice as long" may indicate a mix up between UTF-8 and UTF-16 at some point, though I can't immediately see why that would result in a blank (as opposed to incorrect) string.

Comment: Might be a case of "Garbage In, Garbage Out" - if you've previously stored data without correctly setting the encoding you'll have trouble getting it back again! Also double check that both your database and table are set for UTF-8, otherwise you can get some very odd behaviour

Comment: I checked both database and table encoding, both utf-8. also I removed the data and inserted it again to ensure "Garbage in Garbage out" is not happening. Still the problem is not solved !

Comment: When you look in the database manually, do you see the correct data there?

Comment: The problem is solved. I used HeidiSQL to create the database, initially  with utf 16, and although I changed the database and table properties to utf8 , it didn't make changes. droping and rebuilding the database solved the problem

Comment: actually, I had to use this escaping in name+value case also

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
<property name="connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
```

to session factory configuration.

From Hibernate documentation:

> Arbitrary connection properties can be given by prepending "hibernate.connection" to the connection property name. For example, you can specify a charSet connection property using hibernate.connection.charSet.